# CSS style for only one table of two without selector tag

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is the code that I have to work with.

```
<table width=600>Stuff here
    <table>more stuff here
    </table>
</table>
```

I cant change this code in any way.  I can use CSS to affect this code however.

Therefore, how can I modify the width of table one without forcing a change on the child table?

```
table:first-child {width: 550px !important;}
```

Seems to set both table to 550px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out what the parent element of the outer table is and use `parent > table {}`

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to refer to the outer table by its context. For example, if it is a child of `body`, you can use the selector `body > table`.

If such methods cannot be used, for some reason, you can use an attribute selector (assuming that the inner table has no `width` attribute or has it with a value other than 600):

```
table[width=600] { width: 550px; }
```

Comment: I tried it, and as the attribute selector lacks quotes it does not seem to work properly (in jsfiddle, could have to do with the doctype though or chrome). If the quotes are there, it should work fine. Else you could use `table[width]` assuming there are no other tables with a width attribute. A small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/daRzy/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
table > table { width:550px }
```

Comment: This would affect the inner table, not the outer one, as requested. Besides, it would only work with invalid markup, since in valid HTML, a `table` element cannot be a child of a `table` element.

Comment: i mistook as to if hes trying to have the inner table take that width. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your nested table is inside a `<td>` (the code you posted is invalid html) you might use the following CSS to get what you want:

```
td > table { width: 550px !important }
```